# Allow end user to create custom properties for a class. Make those properties visible to DGV

Tags: vb.net, variables, properties, customization, user-input

Good day.
   Not sure how to word this but please stay with me.
I have several instances of several classes with various properties of various types.
My users (very small business that I work for) would like to perform custom calculations on those variables and display the results in a new DGV column.
For instance

DGV1 uses list(of Myclass) as it's datasource. The columns are automatically added instead of predefined.

One user thinks up a property they would like to always see on dgv1.
He decides that this new property should be the result of 
(Myclass.property1 - Myclass.property2)

Iv'e never done this sort of thing and have no clue where to start. I do know that I can't possibly hard code every possible combination of properties. Also, there's know way for the users foresee every combination that they'll need.

It basically needs to be as flexible as excel. 
I have a logictree style custom filter builder for queering against properties of theses objects. Some of the users also want to be able to use these custom properties as nodes in the filter.

I'm not even sure if there's a way to add a property to a class at run time and in such a manner that it behaves as properties which are hard coded.

I'd be grateful for your thought and advice on this matter. Also, If I'm unclear on anything then I apologize. Please let me know if I need to clarify something.
Thank you, in advance.

*Edit#
I have discovered [Typebuiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2sd82fz7.aspx)  and am reading up on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to add properties to a class on runtime. Once a class is created it's basically set in stone.

You could however have a Dictionary(Of String, Object) to hold the name and value of "properties" in your class. Make all properties like this and you can sort of simulate addable and removable properties. This however is limited to the object.

If you also want your customers to be able to perform calculations, you will have to write a script engine or use one.

I suggest to use a JavaScript engine. With JavaScript you can add properties whenever you want and you have JavaScript as a complete scripting language (JS is not only limited to the web).
I can suggest NiL.JS (https://github.com/nilproject/NiL.JS) as an engine. It is fast and you can easily convert objects back and forth from JS to .Net.

Here is how to use it:

```
Dim o As New YourCustomObject() ' Your object (e.g. has a property x (double))
o.x = 5.0
Dim c As New Context() ' Create a new JS environment
c.DefineVariable("o").Assign(JSValue.Marshal(o)) ' Transfer the variable
c.Eval("o.x = 6.0;") ' Change the value in JS and it will change in .Net
MsgBox(o.x) ' 6.0
```

It's a little more difficult to retrieve properties added in JS, but it is possible. I suggest looking at the examples at the GitHub page.

I don't know about the licensing of Nil.JS but there are similar engine out there.